# How do I restore the clock resolution on my windows box?

Tags: windows

When I run clockres on my machine I get this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>clockres

ClockRes v2.0 - View the system clock resolution
Copyright (C) 2009 Mark Russinovich
SysInternals - www.sysinternals.com

Maximum timer interval: 15.625 ms
Minimum timer interval: 0.500 ms
Current timer interval: 1.000 ms

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I have read the various posts about Chrome being the culprit. Some posts mention WPF applications when ran from within the Visual Studio, others incriminate it to the Sql Server. I run none of these and still get the same result.

How do I restore the windows clock resolution back to being 64 times per second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Input

You can run the following command in a Administrative CMD Prompt:

```
c:\temp> powercfg -energy duration 5
```

This will create an a report called: `C:\temp\energy-report.html`

This report will show you which processes have changed the Clock Latency/Resolution on your computer. Normally these are RTC (Real-Time Communication) applications, but as you have noticed can be Chrome and other applications.

## Output

An (albeit German) example of the output looks like this. *Sorry I don't have access to an English client at the moment.*

#### First Statement in Report: Something has changed

> **Plattform-Zeitgeberauflösung:Plattform-Zeitgeberauflösung**
>
> Die standardmäßige Plattform-Zeitgeberauflösung beträgt 15,6 ms (15625000 ns) und sollte immer dann verwendet werden, wenn sich das System im Leerlauf befindet. Wenn die Zeitgeberauflösung erhöht wird, sind die Technologien zur Prozessorenergieverwaltung möglicherweise nicht wirksam. Die erhöhte Zeitgeberauflösung kann auf eine Multimediawiedergabe oder Grafikanimationen zurückzuführen sein.
>
> Aktuelle Zeitgeberauflösung (100-ns-Einheiten) 10000 **<<=== CURRENT SETTING**
>   Maximale Zeitgeberperiode (100-ns-Einheiten) 156250  **<<== DEFAULT SETTING**

#### Second Statement in Report: The Culprit

> **Plattform-Zeitgeberauflösung:Ausstehende Zeitgeberanforderung**
>
> Von einem Programm oder Dienst wurde eine Zeitgeberauflösung angefordert, die kleiner als die maximale Zeitgeberauflösung der Plattform ist.
>
> Angeforderter Zeitraum 10000  **<<== Requested Clock Latency**
>   ID des anfordernden Prozesses 12592  **<<== Process ID of application requesting different Clock Latency**
>   Pfad des anfordernden Prozesses \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files (x86)\C4B\XPhone Connect Client\C4B.XPhone.Commander.exe  **<<== The culprit**

The information can be separated from each other and can contain different modules inbetween the individual blocks, but you should be able to find the culprit armed with the information provided above.